# Hybris Failed to create cronjob with code 00000BLQ (Error hybrisHTTP34 )

Tags: spring-mvc, ant, cron, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

**Hi guys i have a created a cronjob using impex  below is impex query**

INSERT_UPDATE ServicelayerJob;code[unique=true];springId
;bookstoreEmailJob;bookstoreEmailJob

INSERT_UPDATE CronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);singleExecutable;sessionLanguage(isocode)
;bookstoreEmailCronJob;bookstoreEmailJob;false;en

INSERT_UPDATE Trigger;cronjob(code)[unique=true];cronExpression
;bookstoreEmailCronJob; 0 0 0 * * ?

**and now when i run update from hac i got these error please guide me how to resolve this error below is the detail logs of error.**

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.576 | [1;31mERROR [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultImportService] Import has caused an error, see logs of cronjob with code=00000ATY for further details

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.576 | [m[1;31mERROR [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [/bookstorecore/import/common/essential-data.impex]... FAILED
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.576 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [/bookstorecore/import/common/essential-data_en.impex]...

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.676 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultImportService] Starting import synchronous using cronjob with code=00000ATZ
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.676 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] (00000ATZ) [ImpExImportJob] Starting ImpEx cronjob "ImpEx-Import"
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.776 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] (00000ATZ) [Importer] Finished 1 pass in 0d 00h:00m:00s:101ms - processed: 54, no lines dumped (last pass 0)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.776 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultImportService] Import was successful (using cronjob with code=00000ATZ)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.776 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [/bookstorecore/import/common/essential-data_de.impex]...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/20 17:32:11.876 | [m[32mINFO  [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultImportService] Starting import synchronous using cronjob with code=00000AU0

Comment: hi @Zissouu i have created cronjob when i run impex from hybris hac i got these errors :                                                                                            ERROR [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultImportService] Import has caused an error, see logs of cronjob with code=00000BLQ for further details
ERROR [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [/bookstorecore/import/common/essential-data.impex]... FAILED

Comment: And what do the logs say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't need to write ServiceLayerJob impex if your Job's spring bean entry is extending abstractJobPerformable bean.
And try running impex with header and Table entry in separate lines for Trigger